# Blocking right-click/keyboard on a VNC server

Tags: linux, vnc, flash

I'm planning to host an application I don't have the source for via VNC in a kiosk mode kind of manner. A flash game running server-side, to simplify matters.

First, only part of the window should be visible to the client due to some domain-specific reasons - that can be solved with the -clip argument on some popular VNC servers.

Right-click makes the application work in a manner I'd rather not, and keyboard presses can do as well (for example, Alt+Tab).

How can I prevent users from right-clicking and pressing keyboard buttons during their VNC sessions?